# Adding on update cascade to already exsisting primary keys in oracle

Tags: oracle, database

I already have a table created with a primary key but I forgot to add an on update cascade function to it, is there any way to alter the primary key in oracle so it will do this?.

Answer (score 1):

There is [no UPDATE CASCADE](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5773459616034) in Oracle. Physical primary keys are supposed to be [stable](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8187/should-a-primary-key-be-immutable).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no ALTER statement to do that.

You need to drop and re-create the constraint.

To drop an unnamed primary key constraint, just use:

```
ALTER TABLE foobar DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: I also forgot to name the constraint is it still possible to delete it?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but since the primary key is a foreign key in another table when I try to run the code I get this error:
ORA-02273: this unique/primary key is referenced by some foreign keys.

Comment: @JeffRomig: then you need to drop that foreign key first.

Comment: Now I've run into another problem when I go to the staff table to drop the foreign key I enter the following code:
'ALTER TABLE STAFF
DROP FOREIGN KEY branchNo;' (where branchNo is the name of the foreign key column)
and I get the error message: ORA-00905: missing keyword.

Comment: @JeffRomig: Please check the manual for the correct syntax: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_3001.htm

Answer (score 0):

To drop a constraint from the table you have to use the following syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME
DROP CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINT_NAME
```

If you do not give any name to your constraint, you can find it in your `USER_CONSTRAINTS` schema
`SELECT Constraint_Name, Constraint_Type, Table_name
FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS;`

By default the constraints are saved in the format
`Coni`, where i is the integer which value is always incrementing